# MySQL MONTH() doesn't return correct value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute a query that gets the month from a date and it seems to give me an incorrect moth;

Code is:

```
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(Datum))
```

And Datum is:

```
24/01/2017
```

The result should be 01 or 1 but instead it is 12 and I don't know why... If I don't try to get the moth of that date, it will give me 24/01/2017 so I'm not sure what's wrong...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is exactly the Datum value in unix format?

Comment: The unix format date is 31/12/1969 for some reason EDIT: my other sql server DOES do this correctly...I need this one for testing so I don't mess up the databases on the actual server

Comment: unix timestamp are usually integers. http://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Answer (score 0):

If your `Datum` is `24/01/2017`, try following:

```
month(str_to_date('24/01/2017', '%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to solve your problem.

```
SELECT MONTH(str_to_date('24/01/2017', '%d/%m/%Y'));
```